# Serial Communication between RaspberryPi and CC3D?

Tags: quadcopter, raspberry-pi

I have built a quadcopter with a CC3D FC, using LibrePilot for configuration. Everything is smooth with the tx/rx I used to command the quad with but now I would like to effectively use the RPi as a reciever.

I am aware of the voltage difference and have leveled it with a bidirectional 3.3v to 5v, vice versa, leveler and I have a connection between the Pi and the CC3D via its Flexi port. As I power the Pi, the FC powers on and ESCs give the signal sound.

Now, my question is - how can I now move the motors?
I am aware of the SBUS protocol as an option to emulate the RPi as a receiver running the motors on PWM but how do I practically make this happen?

I would appreciate any feedback.